# Wrap 32-bit native DLL in .NET DLL to use in 64-bit .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, dll, 64-bit, native

I have a 32-bit native DLL which I *dynamically load* and communicate with in a 32-bit .NET application. The 32-bit application is limited by .NET's 2Gb memory limit however, and so I have a 64-bit version available and I have some 64-bit native DLLs which work fine with that, but I have some DLLs which are only available to me in 32-bit.

I've been reading around SO about various workarounds for this using COM or IPC, but wondered if the following might work:

1 - Create an 'Any CPU' .NET DLL.
2 - Load up the 32-bit native DLL in this .NET DLL.
3 - Communicate directly with the .NET DLL from my 64-bit .NET app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this will not work.  If you compile an AnyCPU assembly that depends on a 32-bit native DLL then it will throw an exception if you attempt to load it in x64 mode.  This is no different to the case where you compile your own application as AnyCPU and attempt to load a 32-bit module.

The only option is to create a separate 32-bit process and use some sort of IPC to communicate between the 32 and 64 bit processes.

Comment: There is no dependency though, I'm dynamically loading the DLL. That's why I thought I might get away with it.

Comment: @DerfSkren If you are dynamically loading a DLL then you have a dependency on that DLL.  You cannot load a 32-bit DLL into a 64-bit process.

Comment: I wouldn't call that a dependency, since the application can start with or without the DLL on either architecture, it simply can't find functions with GetProcAddress and hence won't offer the user the functionality found in the DLL. Point taken though and if noone can offer any insight I'll mark you as the answer.

Comment: @DerfSkren What you call it doesn't really matter.  You cannot load 32-bit code in a 64-bit application, no matter how circuitously you try to do it.  What more insight do you want?

Comment: Well, dependency does have a specific meaning in programming, there is no 'throwing an exception' here. Technically, what is the reason I can't load up the registers and stack pointer etc. using the 32-bit calling conventions and jump to the function address (just like a 32-bit process does when running on my 64-bit architecture/OS)? And why is my AnyCPU assembly not able to use the calling conventions of 'any CPU' that is supported? So insight as in being able to explain your assertion, I guess...

Comment: @DerfSkren Compiling as "AnyCPU" simply builds the codebase for both a 32-bit and a 64-bit executable.  64-bit code is completely different from 32-bit code - register usage is different, math uses XMM (x64) instead of x87 (x86), stack frames are completely different, etc.  Native 32-bit code *must* be called in the context of a 32-bit process because the methods do not make any sense in the context of a 64-bit process.  Exception handling would be broken as well (since 32 and 64 bit conventions deal with stack frames in a completely different way).

Comment: @DerfSkren Consider also the restrictions on stack alignment for x64 (ie: 32-bit code is free to trash 64-bit alignment rules), and further that pointers in a 64-bit process can map to memory space that is not accessible to 32-bit code.  What's to stop a 64-bit process from loading a 32-bit DLL into memory space that the DLL cannot even address?  The list goes on.  The only way this could possibly work would be to build a complete virtualization layer between the 32-bit DLL and the 64-bit process.  AFAIK, there are no pre-made tools to do this.